# likelihood for binomial proportion

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, likelihood

> A man must evaluate the proportion $\pi \ (0 \leq \pi \leq 1)$ of diesel vehicles crossing a road. He notes the first 10 cars arriving and records 3 diesel vehicles. I know that $f_Y(y;\pi)\sim Bin(\pi,10)$, so

$$f_Y(y;\pi)=\binom{10}{3}\pi^3(1-\pi)^7$$

Now, the likelihood function is $$L(\pi; y) \propto f_Y(y; \pi)$$
so

$$L(\pi; y) = \pi^3(1-\pi)^7$$

> The man continues the measurement and he notices other 2 diesel vehicles in the next 6 cars. How can he combine the two observations to calculate the likelihood function?

**Edit**

I guess that if he combines the two observations he gets a new $f_Z(z;\pi)\sim Bin(\pi,16)$ with function $$f_Z(z;\pi)=\binom{16}{5}\pi^5(1-\pi)^{11}$$
and a different likelihood funtion $$L(\pi; y) = \pi^5(1-\pi)^{11}$$

Comment: Please add a bit to this question to address what you have tried or what you are confused about.

Comment: @AdamO I edited my initial question with my attempt.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have here. Were you just unsure of your answer?

Comment: @AdamO I never studied this stuff before, so I just asked a confirm :-)